# Initialize formGroup with depending Dropdowns

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have a problem that is solved and working, but it's too complex right now, so I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Basically i have a reactive form with multiple dropdowns that depend on each other.

Example:

```
myFormGroup = formBuilder.group({
  Dropdown1: [''],
  Dropdown2: [''], // selection values depend on Dropdown 1
  Dropdown3: [''], // selection values depend on Dropdown 2
});
```

After the formGroup is created i load possible values for Dropdown1 from a Service and at the same time subscribe to valueChanges of Dropdown1.

Example:

```
loadDropdown1() {
  this.myService.getDropdown1Values().subscribe(
    values => {
      .. // save to local var
      this.subscribeDropdown1Change();
    }
  );
}

subscribeDropdown1Change() {
  this.myFormGroup.controls.Dropdown1.valueChanges
  .pipe(
     // see: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15282
     startWith(this.myFormGroup.controls.Dropdown1.value)
   )
   .subscribe(
     selectedValue => this.loadDropdown2(selectedValue)
  )
}

... and so on
```

This gives me the correct values in the second Dropdown as soon as the first one changes. To initialize the form with existing values i use something like `myFormGroup.patchValue(formData);`. This doesn't trigger the valueChange so i had to add the `startWith()`.

Now for example, if the first dropdown changes you have to reset the values of the depending dropdowns, this also needs additional logic because it shouldn't be reset on the initial valueChange.

If these dropdowns are inside of a FormArray or if the form gets more complex this gets out of hand pretty fast.

**So what i would like to know is, if there is a simpler way to handle this. Initializing a formGroup with depending values is fine. But loading additional data that the depending form components need, is a huge pain with this solution.**

All the information i could find pretty much stops at creating the form with depending values, but do not explain how you would update existing data. Does anyone know a source?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. SO is  about fixing broken code.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I was facing in my project. I have used decorator based validation approach of rxweb validation framework.

I have created a sample application and try to incorporate you scenario. Based upon dropdown change source will be changed and value will be null in nested child properties.

In the sample application I have considered the scenario, when user change the country then state and city formcontrol value should be null and respective source will be bind.

Here is image of example.

[image]

Working [example on stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqerm3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain.component.ts)

You don't need to subscribe the valuechanges. I have refered this article to achieve this : https://medium.com/@oojhaajay/new-way-to-validate-the-angular-reactive-form-2c4fe4f13373